# SQL help on counting the rows of a LEFT JOIN on a condition ignoring the right side

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 2 tables, tickets a tokens. Tokens as a column user_type.

I'm trying to work out how to count all the tickets joined on tokens.ticket_id which don't have a `tokens.user_type == 'ADMIN'`. So `user_type` can equal anything, except admin.

The problem is that there may be 5 other tokens to a ticket.

I know a reasonable about of SQL knowledge but this one has had me stumped for a while.

Also sorry if the title wasn't written correctly.
Thank you,
Kieran!

### edit

I may have explained it wrong. But that still returns more then it should. If it has a ADMIN token it shouldnt show up in the result, otherwise it should show up. And im adding this because stackoverflow was complaining about insubstantial changes to make an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT Tickets.id)
FROM
    Tickets
    INNER JOIN Tokens
        ON Tokens.ticket_id = Tickets.id
        AND Tokens.user_type != 'ADMIN'
```

---

If you need to include tickets with no tokens, this might work:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT Tickets.id)
FROM
    Tickets
    LEFT JOIN Tokens
        ON Tokens.ticket_id = Tickets.id
WHERE
    Tokens.user_type != 'ADMIN'
```

Comment: This will miss counting those tickets with no tokens.

Comment: I may have explained it wrong. But that still returns more then it should. If it has a ADMIN token it shouldnt show up in the result, otherwise it should show up.

Comment: Now, 1. it still misses tickets with no tokens at all.  To fix that you need to move the condition on user_type into the join condition, but more important, if there are multiple tokens and even one has a User_Type not equal to 'ADMIN' that ticket will be counted.  What you would be counting is those tickets that have any user_type other than 'ADMIN', not the tickets that do not have ANY token = 'ADMIN'

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Select Count(*) From Tickets t
Where Not Exists(Select * From tokens
                 Where ticket_Id = t.Ticket_id
                     And user_type ='Admin')
```

Comment: +1 . . . But you should fix the query to have the condition `tokens.ticket_id = tickets.ticket_id`.  The alias `t` has not definition.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an aggregate of a case when function, that way you could say edge case counts as well as totals:

```
declare @Person Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8));

insert into @Person values ('Brett'),('Paul'),('John');

declare @Orders table ( OrderID int identity, PersonID int, Description varchar(32), Amount int);

insert into @Orders values (1, 'Shirt', 20),(1, 'Shirt', 50),(1, 'Shirt', 22),(1, 'Admin', 52),(2, 'Shirt', 22),(2, 'Admin', 52);

Select
    p.person
,   count(case when o.Description != 'Admin' then o.orderID end) as NonAdminOrders
,   count(o.orderID) as TotalOrders
from @Person p
    left join @Orders o on p.personID = o.PersonID
group by p.person
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Tickets.id) - 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Tokens.user_type = 'ADMIN' THEN Tickets.id END)
FROM Tickets
LEFT JOIN Tokens ON Tokens.ticket_id = Tickets.id
```

If your summary doesn't require information from the Tokens table, this could be rewritten more efficiently as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Tickets
LEFT JOIN Tokens ON Tokens.ticket_id = Tickets.id AND Tokens.user_type = 'ADMIN'
WHERE Tokens.ticket_id IS NULL
```